# Use of <%= %> and expression databinding for Write Response

Tags: asp.net

i want write content(summary) with <%= %>  and  expression databinding in below code but do not success!how i can, do it?

```
<asp:Literal Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>' ID="SumLitteral"  runat="server" />
```

Comment: are you using any databound control ? In which databound control ,your literal control exist?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `# sign` with the binding expression, then you need to call `DataBind()` method..

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't use the <%= %> syntax to set a property in a server control**. You can only use a databinding expression, which you actually have already in your example. Assuming this is part of a Repeater (or some other templated control) and the DataSource is made up of items that have a Summary property, your code above would work. If it's not part of a repeater you can still use a databinding expression, but Eval("Summary") would not have a meaning that makes sense to me, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that the "Summary" value is not actually displaying, its likely that databind() is not being called on the page or the control.